# Grails JMS messages fails to persist data

Tags: hibernate, grails, jms

In my Grails 2.5.0 application I want to make a embedded middle ware using ActiveMQ and JMS.
Thus, I have installed plugins for JMS and activeMQ.
From controller, I am sending messages to jmsService and I have listener created to receive data in queue. The data is a JSON data which contains lot of data which I need to persist via different Domain objects.
Data been propagated from controller to listener correctly.

The problem is, while I called the related service method with the data, it gives me a lot of hibernate exceptions.
But, if the service method is called directly from the controller with controller, everything goes perfect.

I suspect, there is some session conflicts or loss of hibernate session of something similar to that.

Can anybody help me to get rid of the issue?

The error message looks like:

```
[01:51:45.072] ERROR org.hibernate.AssertionFailure an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session)
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.mycomp.domain.Client entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getValues(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1185)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1261)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.FindPersistentMethod$1.doInHibernate(FindPersistentMethod.java:163)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:407)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:339)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.FindPersistentMethod.doInvokeInternal(FindPersistentMethod.java:103)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractStaticPersistentMethod.invoke(AbstractStaticPersistentMethod.java:79)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractStaticPersistentMethod.invoke(AbstractStaticPersistentMethod.java:72)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateGormStaticApi.find(HibernateGormStaticApi.groovy:570)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I been able to resolve my problem by adding message converter.
Later I changed my code by using camel-case.
I pushed all the messages from controller to ActiveMQ and using camel-cases picked the data and sent to target service Unmarshalling it.